# How to use SearchView from dark theme in Light Appcompat theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light theme and using SearchView which by default shows dark texts and icons..

How can I use SearchView defined in Theme.AppCompat in this light theme?

Already tried below but not working?

```
<style name="Theme.App.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.SearchView</item>
</style>
```

Even using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar as base theme does not show the white texts and icons..

It can be done by overriding all values,but I just need to use defaults provided in Dark theme..

Comment: So you're using your `SearchView` in the default action bar (i.e., you never call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`), yet even with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` the `SearchView` appears with dark text?

Comment: setSupportActionBar is being used.. I don't see any reason why it will affect SearchView.. yes it coming with dark texts but I am using setSupportActionBar..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per [this pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/AV2ooBWY1iy), `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` only applies if you are using the AppCompat provided Action Bar. If you are using a `Toolbar`, then you should be using a `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme. To theme your Toolbar appropriate for a dark background, you need to add `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

`SearchView` will then pull the correct resources needed to work on a dark background.

Comment: great..  I wish I knew it earlier.. Spent days fixing other black and white related issues by customising almost all aspects..

Comment: what if the SearchView is not part of Toolbar?

Comment: @RahulKumar - you can apply the `android:theme` to the SearchView directly

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks for the reply. I did that after wandering through different posts :-)